# Post.Username wont display inside haml?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, haml

Okay so probably a really straight forward question to answer I guess. I seem to have broken a feature of my app which displays the username of the person who submitted the post (in my case 'pin').

This all happened around the time I added usernames to the database(devise) as previously I was only displaying email addresses and felt that wasn't really what I wanted.

Tl;dr: = **pin.user.username** (*app/views/pins/index.html.haml*) Doesn't show the username of the person who submitted the post. However it will display email with **pin.user.email**.

Here is my PinsController (Pin in my case is the Post in devise)

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

attr_accessor :username

def index
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
end

def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
end

def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)

    if @pin.save
        redirect_to @pin, notice: "Fit was successfully created"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
        redirect_to @pin, notice: "Fit was successfully updated"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

def upvote
    @pin.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
end

private

def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image)
end

def find_pin
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

Here is my index.html.haml

```
#pins.transitions-enabled
- @pins.each do |pin|
    .box.panel.panel-default
        = link_to (image_tag pin.image.url), pin
        %h2= link_to pin.title, pin
        %p.user
            Submitted by
            = pin.user.username
```

My Schema shows this for Users

```
  add_index "pins", ["user_id"], name: "index_pins_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "username"
end
```

I've attached my git just incase you need some specific details
https://github.com/thgilartlU/MyFitIdentity

Comment: You should restructure your question to be  a minimal complete verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Right now, anyone who might be able to help you would have to go through your entire code base to find out what's going on.

Comment: @JChrist Thanks for the tip! I'll see how I can clean this up.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know well haml, but, surfing on your code I've found "attr_accessor :username" in your pins_controller. Seems not have any reference on your schema. Maybe do some "interferences" ?

Comment: @rfellons I'm not sure what interferences are. I've only been coding ruby for a couple of days.

I've removed attr_accessor :username from my pins controller as I've noticed I've already got it in my application controller anyway. I've updated the main post with my schema as that might be useful.

Comment: `attr_accessor :username` shouldn't be anywhere in your controllers or models.

Comment: @Iceman THANK YOU! After removing attr_accessor :username from the User.rb file it seems to have fixed my issue along with I'm sure adding :username to my pin_params as suggested by KcUS_unico. Thanks to both of you for the help! I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
attr_accessor :username

def username=(username)
  @username = username
end
```

from your `user.rb` model file, it messes up ActiveRecord

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not haml it is that the username you are trying to display seems to be empty. Your haml structure looks just fine. 
As mentioned in your `pin_params` is not permitted `username`, so make sure to permit and get it saved into the DB. Than your haml should work.

Comment: I've updated my pins_controller to include:

     def pin_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image, :username)
 end

and after checking if the user had a username with @u = User.all it is showing a username:

   created_at: "2017-02-06 18:47:44", updated_at: "2017-02-11 12:54:04", username: "ultralight">

However my index.html.haml still does not show the username of the person who created the pin.

Comment: You should make sure that you can access the username like this also in your console. pin.user.username. The haml is fine.